# ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to load data from Google BigQuery into Spark running on Google Dataproc (I'm using Java). I tried to follow instructions on here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

I get the error: "`ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery`."

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.virtualpairprogrammers</groupId>
    <artifactId>learningSpark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-bigquery_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1-beta</version>
            <classifier>shaded</classifier>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.virtualpairprogrammers.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After adding the dependency to my pom.xml it was downloading a lot to build the .jar, so I think I should have the correct dependency? However, Eclipse is also warning me that "The import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery is never used".

This is the part of my code where I get the error:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("testingSql")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("bigquery")
                .option("table","project.dataset.tablename")
                .load()
                .cache();
```

Comment: Well, the example and your code didn't match the class name.

Comment: I think you only added BQ connector as compile time dependency, but it is missing at runtime. You need to either make a uber jar which includes the connector in your job jar, or include it when you submitting the job `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery_2.11:0.9.1-beta`

Comment: @Dagang yes, including it with the job solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only added BQ connector as compile time dependency, but it is missing at runtime. You need to either make a uber jar which includes the connector in your job jar (the doc needs to be updated), or include it when you submit the job `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery_2.11:0.9.1-beta`.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and updated the format from "bigquery" to "com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery" and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the dependency in the build.sbt and using "com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery" in format as suggested by Peter resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Hi Jas  Welcome! The OP stated in their question that they’re using Java; they reference a `pom.xml` and so it’s safe to assume they’re using maven, and not sbt.  As such I think @Peter’s answer covers your suggestion. Your contribution is definitely appreciated! I highly encourage further contribution to Stackoverflow :) i would advise more carefully reading over the existing answers going forward.

Comment: @tjheslin1, the point Jas made is relevant for the question, which is making change to format. The answers does not has to be confined to the build system that question asks.

by the way,  changing the format value from "bigquery" to "com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery" does not work for me.  on spark 3.3.1 with bigquery-all-dependency jar which already includes the class: bigquery.DefaultSource