# PySpark with BiqQuery connector. Failed to find data source: bigquery

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, spark-bigquery-connector

I need to write PySpark's result to BiqQuery. According to https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector , i use following:

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .config("spark.jars.packages",\
                "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.27.1")\
            .getOrCreate()
    spark_context = spark.sparkContext
```

Each attemp of saving,

```
    data.toDF(schema) \
                .write.format("bigquery") \
                .option("table", "tmp-project:tmpdataset.tmp_table") \
                .save()
```

leads to an exception:

```
*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html*
```

Also tried, but same result:

1. setup reference directly to gcs 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar'
2. download locally 'spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar' and setup local path. The file according to logs definitely exists.
3. option to setup the jar as argument like `pyspark --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.27.1.jar` is not available for right now.
4. Updated the format from "bigquery" to "com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery".

*PySpark version 3.0.0*
*scala version 2.12.10*

The code below returns an empty result:

```
[spark_context._jsc.sc().jars().apply(i) for i in range(jvc.sc().jars().length())]
```

**UPD**
Upgrade spark to 3.1.1, using using local downloaded jar with `chmod 777` under it changed behavior, but have not solve the issue yet:

```
spark_context._jsc.sc().listJars()
```

returns `Vector(spark://<...>.svc:<port>/jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13-0.27.1.jar)`

```
spark_context._jsc.sc().jars()
```

returns `ArrayBuffer(./<...>/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13-0.27.1.jar)`

Also new log appeared:

```
SparkContext: Added JAR ./<...>/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13-0.27.1.jar at spark://<...>.svc:<port>/jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13-0.27.1.jar with timestamp <timestamp>
```

Comment: Where are you submitting this? On Dataproc?

Comment: @RonakJain, it is already running inside container, without my management. I am new in pyspark, so I am open for suggestions to provide more details/context.

Comment: Inside container? Are you running it on your local or on Google Dataproc Cluster(i.e. Managed Spark Cluster)? You can update the post with your environment details that'll help finding the cause

Comment: Hi @VVildVVolf, can you try the solution provided in this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678015/classnotfoundexception-failed-to-find-data-source-bigquery)? Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @RonakJain, the Google Dataproc Cluster is not used, it run on custom cluster hosted on kubernetes (or not hosted, but using kubernetes). Trying to find out more details.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar, thank you for suggestion, but different formats do not help as well.

Comment: @VVildVVolf Got it, putting JAR on local (i.e. inside container/pod) didn't work?

Comment: @RonakJain, yes, local placed jar files did not work. Just found wanted to respond, that copying to /opt/spark/jars/ helps. Would you like to make it your answer?

Comment: Awesome will add. Still not sure why the Maven dependency (packages) method didn't work. Have you checked the logs if it was actually being resolved? There are actually few other ways to define JAR to put in K8s deployment YAML, if you can share that it'll be great.

Comment: @RonakJain, I have not seen anything interesting in logs, except I written manually (that's why I was not able to make more specific question, not just "It does not work") - except the first UPD after update spark 3.0 -> 3.1. If you know any specific mask, I will check if it was written.

Comment: Hi @VVildVVolf,In this method the data is written directly to BigQuery using the BigQuery Storage Write API. In order to enable this option, please set the writeMethod option to direct, as shown below:`df.write \   .format("bigquery") \   .option("writeMethod", "direct") \   .save("dataset.table")`. For more information, you can check this [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector).Does this help?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, thank you for details, as I written above I have already found solution, but since RonakJain written before I expect their answer. If the answer will not be provided, I will respond with my answer. Thank you for help!

Comment: Hi @VVildVVolf, can you post your solution so that it will help the community in their research as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to copy all jar files to `/opt/spark/jars/`. Just keeping this file locally on docker container and load in runtime did not help, but moving to exact this path - helped. If anyone else will bump with this issue, you can try to tune `SPARK_CLASSPATH` env - it might also help. `SPARK_CLASSPATH` was referenced to `/opt/spark/jars/` in my case.